# Select Row Data In Table React

Tags: reactjs

I have a table being populated with API data and at the end of each row (still within the table in a blank column) I have placed a "select" button which is responsible for storing the data into a global variable to be accessed on other pages. My question is, how do I set up the onClick event for the button to specifically take the data from the row it sits in?

Global Context:

```
const {customerInformation, setCustomerInformation} = 
useContext(GlobalContext);
```

OnClick Event:

```
const selectCustomer = (rowValue) => {
    console.log("Row Data", rowValue)
    var customerInfo = rowValue;
    console.log("Customer Info", customerInfo);
}
```

Row Return:

```
{ props.customerData.listOfContacts.contact.map(contacts => {

                    return (
                        <tr key={contacts.id}>
                        <td>{contacts.firstName}</td>
                        <td>{contacts.lastName}</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>{contacts.listOfContact_PersonalAddress.contact_Address[0].streetAddressName}</td>
                        <td>{contacts.listOfContact_Emails.email[0].emailAddress}</td>
                        <td>{contacts.listOfContact_Phones}</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>{contacts.listOfContact_AlternatePhone}</td>
                        <td><button className="customer-select-button" onClick={() => selectCustomer(contacts)}>Select</button></td>
                        </tr> 
                        )
                    }                            
                )}
```

Comment: Could you add the code that renders the rows?

Comment: Just added the code, sorry about that

Comment: The selectCustomer function looks like it should already get the value of the row. If you add setCustomerInformation(rowValue) or setCustomerInformation(customerInfo) and have the Provider of the GlobalContext wrapped around every component that need access to it, it should work. Or do you have a different problem?

Comment: So I've tried setCustomerInformation(rowValue) and setCustomerInformation(customerInformation) in the selectCustomer function but when I try to console log customerInformation it's coming up empty. That's the main issue I'm having right now, not being able to pass that data to my global variable customerInformation.

Comment: But the values are showing up in the table/row?

Comment: Yes the table gets the data and I'm able to capture that data in rowValue, it shows when I console log it. But for some reason customerInfo isn't capturing it.

Comment: I wrote up a quick example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-hooks-rn7lz.

Comment: Is there a special reason for you to save `rowValue` in another variable other than in the context? Then you could try to use `let` or `const` instead of `var`, as these are block scoped (https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-hooks-rn7lz).

Comment: It was only for console logging purposes, just to make sure I was correctly capturing that data. Thank you so much, let me take a look at these once I'm in front of a computer. Appreciate all your help!